# Angular 2 rxjs switchmap returns Observable<Object>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building a typescript angular 2 app and using rxjs. I am following the example here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#stq=formgroup&stp=1

All though I am trying to strongly type my return signatures with typescript.  This may be my problem in that you aren't supposed to.  But it seems like you should be able to.

Suppose I have service that is typed to return an Observable>.

```
 public search(term: string) : Observable<Array<MyModel>> { // http call }
```

In my component I am attempting to listen to this observable stream and return the results.

```
 private search = new Subject<Search>();
 results: Observable<Array<MyModel>>;

 ngOnInit() {
     this.results = this.search
        .debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(search => {
            return service.search(search.term); // returns Observable<Array<MyModel>>
        });
  }
```

This doesn't compile with the message `Cannot convert type Observable<Object> to type Observable<MyModel[]>>`

I don't understand why switchmap is returning an Observable instead of my type. Do I need to map it again before giving it to results?  Is this a typescript typings issue with the return signature of switchmap?

Comment: I think you just need a cast.

Comment: I had tried that but ignorantly casted the return statement instead of on the end of the switchmap chain which is where the cast belongs.  That was a boneheaded thing to miss.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Typescript might have wrong type inference, I would try one of the following:

give your handler a return type:

```
.switchMap((search): Observable<Array<MyModel>> => {
        return service.search(search.term); // returns Observable<Array<MyModel>>
    });
```

and if this doesn't work, "compromise" for changing the type of the results variable to:

```
 results: Observable<any>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually right. However, it's unclear what line caused the error without a stack trace.

In the `ngOnInit()` method you call:

```
this.results = this.search
    .debounceTime(..)
    ...
```

This chain of operators always returns an `Observable` which is not as the `result` property expects (`Observable<Array<MyModel>>`) because the `Subject`'s generic is `Search`.

Operator `switchmap()` returns always an `Observable`. Its return type has nothing to do with the callable.

You should be able to solve this by simply typecasting the result:

```
this.results = Observable<MyModel[]>this.search
    .debounceTime(..)
    ...
```